# How would I separate multiple elements added from javascript into my HTML?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to reproduce the following image in HTML / Javascript:

[image: Results Page correct]

This is how far I have got:

[image]

This is my code in javascript:

```
function createLink(text, parentElement) {
    var a = document.createElement('a');
    var linkText = document.createTextNode(text);
    a.appendChild(linkText);
    temp1 = text.replace("/","-");
    temp2 = res1.replace("/","-");
    a.href = "http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/" + temp2 + ".csv";
    parentElement.appendChild(a);
}

var txtFile8 = new XMLHttpRequest();
txtFile8.open("GET", "http://www.drakedesign.co.uk/mdmarketing/uploads/date.txt", true);
txtFile8.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (txtFile8.readyState === 4) {  // Makes sure the document is ready to parse.
        if( (txtFile8.status == 200) || (txtFile8.status == 0) ) { // Makes sure it's found the file.
            allText8 = txtFile8.responseText;
            arrayOfLines8 = allText8.match(/[^\r\n]+/g);
            for (i = 0; i < arrayOfLines8.length - 1; i++) { 
                createLink(arrayOfLines8[i], document.getElementById("previousResultsList"));
            }        
        }
    }
};

txtFile8.send(null);
```

This code snippet does the following:
reads an online textfile containing dates.
separates each date into an element in an array.
runs through a for loop making each date into a link in the div previousResultsList

I am writing to ask how I could possibly separate the elements added to the div:"previousResultsList"

The first problem is:

1) Separating the elements out simply one after another in a list form.

2) How would I separate the dates into chunks for any dates in that month and attach the image on the side.

Comment: Can you link to a fiddle or dev site to show the HTML/CSS?

Comment: bonus??? is this a wish list?

Answer (score 1):

I'm guessing it has something to do with CSS and `position: aboslute` based on the screenshot.  Can't do much more unless you post some HTML and CSS.

I have a working example here https://jsfiddle.net/tkcohpqv/20/

Add this in your function and it will stack and separate the `a` as long as the `parentElement` width is less than the width of 2 elements on the same line.

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
$(a).css('position', '');
$(a).css('display', 'block');
$(a).css('float', 'left');
```

Comment: Hi there it is positioned absolutely. Im asking as to how I would move each element into a single column using javascript I'll recreate it now.

Comment: I updated fiddler and my answer.  If you really need the absolute value to remain unchanged I'll need to see the rest of your code because styling isn't my forte.

Answer (score 0):

I solved this issue by editing the position in the CSS to relative and edited my code by adding:

```
        var br = document.createElement('br');
        parentElement.appendChild(br);
```

to the end of my createLink() function.